# Best practice to transform ipad app to iphone app?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, xib, universal-code

I have made an iPad application and know I want to make an unique application for iPad / iPhone. I have started to create a new xib and modify my code with idiom to detect the system the app is running on. But I have some questions: How can I reuse my ipad implementation? Given the files: iphone.xib, iphone.h, iphone.m, ipad.xib, ipad.m, ipad.h, what is the best way to prevent adding the same code in iphone.m and ipad.m ?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following link that explains how to create an universal apps : http://blog.corywiles.com/creating-a-universal-ios-app-tutorial